# Rails errors doesn't work on controllers? how to handle error then?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following action to confirm a PIN code.

```
def create
  @confirm = User.where(:email => params[:user][:email]).last
  errors[:base] << "Subscription not found" if @confirm.nil?
  respond_with(@confirm)
end
```

If the object doesn't exist I'm getting the following error

```
NameError in ConfirmsController#create

undefined local variable or method `errors' for #<ConfirmsController:0x007f921de173d0>
```

Why it doesn't recognize errors and how can I handle error for this case?

Comment: errors need to be attached to an ActiveModel object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors as you are using them are typically on the ActiveRecord model. If you want to display an error message try using the flash method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@confirm.errors[:base] << ...
```

should do the trick

Comment: unfortunately @confirm is nil in this case.